# How to add obj to db with sqlmodel

Tags: python, database, fastapi, pydantic, sqlmodel

I am new to FastAPI. How can i create record in db using sqlmodel and databases packages?

```
class Hero(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    name: str = Field(index=True)
    secret_name: str
    age: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, index=True)

    team_id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, foreign_key="team.id")
    team: Optional[Team] = Relationship(back_populates="heroes")
```

```
@app.post("/hero", description="Create new hero")
async def create_hero(data: Hero):
    hero = Hero(**data.dict())
    q = insert(Hero).values(**hero.dict())
    h_id = await db.execute(q)
```

When i finally try to do this, it shows me:

```
asyncpg.exceptions.NotNullViolationError: null value in column "id" of relation "hero" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, spider, black, 18, null).
```

Referring to the sqlmodel docs, id will be set automatically, but using **sqlmodel.Session**.
How to do the same thing with

```
import databases


db = databases.Database("postgresql+asyncpg://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/testdb")
```

Comment: What's `insert` and `db` in your `create_hero` function? Usually you'd work with an SQLAlchemy session to add these objects as shown in https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/automatic-id-none-refresh/#commit-the-changes-to-the-database

Comment: db is databases.Database object i mentioned above. Insert is https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/dml.html

Comment: As @MatsLindh writes, SQLModel is designed to wirk with a `Session`, and trying to mix it with the `databases` package will probably lead to headaches.

Comment: What is the reason for trying to bring `databases` into the mix? SQLModel is designed to work with an SQLAlchemy session (async support in SQLAlchemy was introduced as part of 1.4: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/asyncio.html)

Answer (score 1):

As some comments suggested, you should probably not use `databases` together with `SQLModel`. The beauty of `SQLModel` is (among many other things) that the database inserts are so simple: You just add your model objects to a database session and commit.

Another suggestion is to make use of the FastAPI [dependencies](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/dependencies-with-yield/) to automatically initialize, start, inject and finally close a session in every route.

Here is a working example:

```py
from typing import Optional

from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio.engine import create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio.session import AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import sessionmaker
from sqlmodel import Field, SQLModel


api = FastAPI()

db_uri = "postgresql+asyncpg://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/testdb"
engine = create_async_engine(db_uri, future=True)
session_maker = sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession)


@api.on_event('startup')
async def initialize_db():
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(SQLModel.metadata.drop_all)
        await conn.run_sync(SQLModel.metadata.create_all)


async def get_session() -> AsyncSession:
    session = session_maker()
    try:
        yield session
    finally:
        await session.close()


class Hero(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    name: str = Field(index=True)
    secret_name: str
    age: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, index=True)

    ...


@api.post("/hero", description="Create new hero")
async def create_hero(hero: Hero, session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_session)):
    session.add(hero)
    await session.commit()
    await session.refresh(hero)
    return hero
```

Note that for testing purposes I simply drop and (re-)create all database tables on startup.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Amazing implementation! works for me